# Is using MS TFS 2010 for Excel files a good idea?

Tags: excel

My team currently uses Microsoft Visual Source Safe 2005 for its versioning/file management. Most of our work is Excel files and other binaries which contain code. We place very little raw code (plain text files) in the repository.

We're looking at switching away from VSS for all the usual reasons and looking at MS Team Foundation Server 2010, since the company already owns it.

I am wondering if TFS will be a good fit for our needs. We create a lot of small, short-term projects, with a small set of binary files in each. We typically have only one, two or three developers on each team.

Is TFS overkill for this? Is there a way to strip out all of the team management, reporting, etc... and just use TFS for versioning / file management? I really want the web interface and the improved remote access and so on but am concerned about all this other stuff in there that we won't use. I'm especially concerned about how closely TFS ties into Visual Studio since we don't do much work in VS at all.

Thanks for any experiences, ideas, etc... you can share.

Answer (score 2):

Source control systems are optimized to handle text files.  They can be used for binary files but they are generally not ideal.

Have you considered using a Sharepoint document repository to store your files?  It will keep previous versions and you can open and save your files directly within Excel.  If you have Windows Server 2003 or later you already have a license for Sharepoint so there is no additional cost.  Note that there are 3 flavors of Sharepoint

- WSS - Windows Sharepoint Services, included in Windows Server
- MOSS  - Microsoft Office Sharepoint Server.  This is a separate product and has extra cost involved.
- Sharepoint 2010 - Also has extra cost plus bigger hardware requirements.

If you haven't used Sharepoint before you should probably start with WSS.

Comment: We have a Sharepoint server running now, doing general intaranet stuff. I'll have to look into the possibility of using it for this new purpose. Thanks much for this idea.

Answer (score 0):

TFS is more than just a source code repository and from your needs it does seem to be an overkill. All things considered though, you should move away from Visual SourceSafe. VSS has a history of getting corrupt if not maintained regularly.

Have you considered another repository such as [Subversion](http://subversion.apache.org/) ? It has very simple maintenance and fairly easy to use. And free. Please note, I use both TFS and Subversion regularly and i'm just basing my recommendation on your question.

[edit] One thing about TFS is that all your users will require Visual Studio installed to interact with it. It will be an overkill to do that when all they require is pushing and pulling Excel files out of a repository. [Tortoise SVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) is a client for Subversion that integrates into the Windows shell so interacting with Subversion for your users will mean right-clicking in File Explorer in Windows. Much more usable for non-tech users.

Comment: I did look into SVN and Tortoise SVN but decided my co-workers wouldn't use it; they will see it as "too technical". They want a GUI, like VSS had. That's not me; that's what I am dealing with.   thanks for the thoughts anyway.

Comment: what the hell? TFS is overkill but not SVN? ok. btw, with the powertools you can get it to work outside of Visual Studio, you only need a TFS client CAL (which depending on how you aquired TFS you may already have). I agree though that putting office files into TFS is not ideal.